# Error getting while using scipy.stats in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame of 3*17 rows and columns. I am trying to find pearsonr value for row b and c using code

```
scipy.stats.pearsonr(x='b', y='c')
```

I am getting error -> len() of unsized object
How to get the result p value using pearson test?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give array to scipy.pearson, so if you have a dataframe `df` with two columns "x" and "y", the correlation coefficient is given by:

```
scipy.stats.pearsonr(x=df["b"], y=df["c"])
```